# Passing (Asp.Net) Session variable (uploaded by uploadify) from webmethod to same page?

Tags: session, variables, uploadify, webmethod

When i try to get uploaded filename from generic handler (upload.ashx)  using session its ok, no problem. I can also use webmethod on samepage and uploadify works great, but Session["fileName"] is getting null. Is there anything wrong on my code? Do i only need to use generic handler to get filename?

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]      
    public void LoadPicture(HttpContext context)
    {
            try
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["Filedata"]; 

            context.Session["fileName"] = file.FileName;
```

....................Some resize and save image codes.........

```
            context.Response.Write("1");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write("0");
        }
   }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (_modelService = new ModelService())
        {
            ModelEntity _models = new ModelEntity();
                 ......some codes....
            _models.modelphoto = Session["fileName"].ToString();
            _modelService.ModelAdd(_models);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Uploadify uses Flash. Flash doesn't send cookies. In ASP.NET sessions are tracked by cookies. So, no session with uploadify, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But i can handle Session with generic handler (IRequiresSessionState).i just wonder why i can't use webmethod like this. Thank you

Comment: How are you handling session with a generic handler? Can you show your code?

Comment: public class Upload : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
                context.Session["fileName"] = file.FileName;//it's works

                context.Response.Write("1");
            }
            catch
            {
                context.Response.Write("0");
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: In this example you are writing to the session, not reading from it.

Comment: yeah thats all i wanted to ask it :)  webmethods can't write Session? or can't read session created in webmethods. sorry for my inscrutable question